# Jenkins Job getting failed if pointed to Master branch

Tags: jenkins

My code recently moved to production and we need to fix an issue in the Hotfix branch. The issue been fixed and merged to the Release branch. Now, the final production code is merged into Master.

We created a Jenkins job. We entered the branch as master and run the Jenkins Job. The build failed with an exception with NPM error. But if I point it to the Release branch in the Jenkins job, the Jenkins build is successful.

But locally, both the master and Release branch, the code is successful. What might be the issue?

Comment: Might be dependency issue @ server. Please update the packages and try again. Also update the question with screenshot and exception logs.

Comment: Can you compare the package.json file from both the branches and share the difference?